# Cannot find module "algorithms/RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5" using Angular 6 and rdflib 0.19.0

Tags: angular, webcrypto-api, solid

I'm developing an Angular6+ [solid-app](https://github.com/solid/solid-spec#overview) ([codebase](https://github.com/sentenza/ng-solid-material)). The app itself depends on:

```
"crypto-js": "^3.1.9-1",
"rdflib": "^0.19.0",
"solid-auth-client": "^2.2.6",
"stream": "0.0.2",
"webcrypto": "^0.1.1",
"zone.js": "^0.8.26"
```

What I'm trying to do is deleting a RDF resource using [`rdflib.UpdateManager.update()`](https://github.com/linkeddata/rdflib.js/blob/fb4b05c945a00f88ee5f8910e2c7c00a3b3ffc8c/src/update-manager.js#L636):

```
$rdf.UpdateManager(this.store).update(toBeDeleted, [], (uri, ok, message, response) => {
  if (ok) {
    console.log('DELETED')
  } else {
    console.warn(message)
  }
})
```

You can find more the JSDoc about the `UpdateManager` [here](http://linkeddata.github.io/rdflib.js/doc/UpdateManager.html) and an introduction of rdflib.js [here](https://rawgit.com/linkeddata/rdflib.js/Documentation/Documentation/webapp-intro.html).

Now, using Firefox `63.0b12 (64-bit)`, I keep getting the following error which I think could be related to the fact that accessing to the *WebCrypto API* [should be restricted to secure origins](https://www.chromium.org/blink/webcrypto) (which is to say `https://` pages). The same error is fired when using Opera.

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot find module "../algorithms/RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5". ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Cannot find module "../algorithms/RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5".
at webpackEmptyContext (algorithms sync:2)
at SupportedAlgorithms.normalize (SupportedAlgorithms.js:84)
at SubtleCrypto.importKey (SubtleCrypto.js:279)
at RSASSA_PKCS1_v1_5.importKey (RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5.js:124)
at Function.importKey (JWA.js:113)
at Function.importKey (JWK.js:46)
at Function.issueFor (PoPToken.js:57)
at webid-oidc.js:183
at fetchWithCredentials (authn-fetch.js:63)
at authn-fetch.js:41 Error: Cannot find module "../algorithms/RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5".
at webpackEmptyContext (http://localhost:4200/main.js:11:10)
at SupportedAlgorithms.normalize (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:132732:107)
at SubtleCrypto.importKey (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:132336:51)
at RSASSA_PKCS1_v1_5.importKey (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:124747:28)
at Function.importKey (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:125342:34)
at Function.importKey (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:125411:18)
at Function.issueFor (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:127189:18)
at http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:185374:44
at fetchWithCredentials (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:184423:49)
at http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:184401:16
```

**Am I missing a npm dependency? What is the root cause of this issue?**

Answer (score 1):

I get the same error when calling this code:

```
import auth from 'solid-auth-client';

// for example in a button click handling, this gives me the error:
auth.logout();
```

Using yarn, webpack 4 and babel 7

Dependencies:

```
"@material-ui/core": "^3.2.0",
"rdflib": "^0.19.0",
"react": "^16.5.2",
"react-dom": "^16.5.2"
```

The way the "@trust/webcrypto" module (version 0.9.2) handles dynamic loading of other modules triggers a warning in my build:

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/@trust/webcrypto/src/algorithms/SupportedAlgorithms.js 84:22-60
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
 @ ./node_modules/@trust/webcrypto/src/algorithms/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/@trust/webcrypto/src/SubtleCrypto.js
 @ ./node_modules/@trust/webcrypto/src/Crypto.js
 @ ./node_modules/@trust/webcrypto/src/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/@solid/oidc-rp/src/AuthenticationRequest.js
 @ ./node_modules/@solid/oidc-rp/src/RelyingParty.js
 @ ./node_modules/@solid/oidc-rp/src/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/solid-auth-client/lib/webid-oidc.js
 @ ./node_modules/solid-auth-client/lib/solid-auth-client.js
 @ ./node_modules/solid-auth-client/lib/index.js
 @ ./src/main/index.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000 @babel/polyfill ./src/main/index.js
```

Sounds somewhat related...

Comment: I have reported this as an issue to https://github.com/anvilresearch/webcrypto/issues/79

Comment: However, the module *@trust/webcrypto* is a nodejs module, and is not written to work in a web browser. For instance, it calls on openssl for key generation.

Solid libraries for web applications need to use another library than @trust/webcrypto... it seems.

Answer (score 1):

[Dmitri Zagidulin](https://github.com/dmitrizagidulin) answered my issue (and my pull request for what I thought was a workaround) here: https://github.com/anvilresearch/webcrypto/pull/80#issuecomment-431115569

The `@trust/webcrypto` module is only intended as a NodeJS module on backend. To exclude it from webpack bundling, one replaces it with an external module (provided by the browser) such as this:

```
externals: {
  '@trust/webcrypto': 'crypto',
  'text-encoding': 'TextEncoder',
}
```

PS: he also recommented externalizing the *text-encoding* module, which is also a browser available module.

Comment: Where did you place this `externals` definition? Is it possible to use it in `angular.json`?

Comment: I don't know how angular configuration works. Sorry.

The configuration I mentioned was for Webpack config file.